# How to compile/build DownZemAll from source?

Tags: open-source

I have recently come back to using a Mac and want to use a download manager (DownZemAll https://setvisible.github.io/DownZemAll/) that I was using on Windows. While the website says it is "for Mac OS X", there is no actual installer available.
I have Xcode and Homebrew installed, but have searched online for instructions on how to compile/build without success.
I am using Catalina, if that helps any. Thanks.

Comment: did you see this page: https://setvisible.github.io/DownZemAll/category/download-advanced.html#download-plateform-macos ? it lists some files for macOS. Are the DMGs not enough ? Also, if it's an add-on for chrome/ FF, you won't be able to use it on safari anyway

Comment: the "Portable" link gives a "file not found" page and the other link leads to a 404 page.

Comment: https://github.com/setvisible/DownZemAll/issues/2#issuecomment-633098935 try downloading the "DownZemAll_v2.0.3_x86_64.tar.gz".https://github.com/setvisible/DownZemAll/releases

Answer (score 1):

The process seems similar to that on Linux.

See `DEVELOPERS.md` in the source code you can download from https://github.com/setvisible/DownZemAll/releases > assests > source code.

Jump straight to the section named "Build with GCC or MinGW"

Install the requirements Boost and Qt5. Use brew to install them to stop the files from being scattered all over the place. Also it'd be easy to locate the file paths you'd need later.

Unzip the source code folder.

```
 cd ~/Downloads/DownZemAll
 mkdir ./build && cd ./build
```

Now edit `3rd/boost/CMakeLists.txt`. Just below the line `find_package(Boost 1.58.0)`, add another line, `set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "absolute path to boost libraries")`.

Now in terminal, assuming you're in `build` folder, run

```
make -S ../ -B . -j 4 
make install
```

Run tests if you wish.

Comment: got to right here:

agarza@MacBook-ag build % make -s ../ -B . -j 4
agarza@MacBook-ag build % make install
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.

Comment: Just realized the "S" was supposed to be uppercase. Copied your text and tried again, got to right here:

agarza@MacBook-ag build % make -S ../ -B . -j 4
make: Nothing to be done for `../'.
make: Nothing to be done for `.'.
agarza@MacBook-ag build %

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to mess with the cmakelists.txt files. I can check tomorrow after I download the dependencies. but before putting so much efforts, its best to ask the developer if it'd even build on Mac or not.

Comment: Tried re-running the build and got the following:

agarza@MacBook-ag build % make -S ../ -B . -j 4
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
agarza@MacBook-ag build %

Comment: Run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` If Xcode is in `/Applications` folder. If you don't have it installed, run `xcode-select -r`

Comment: same as before:

agarza@MacBook-ag build % make -S ../ -B . -j 4 
make: Nothing to be done for `../'.
make: Nothing to be done for `.'.